# setAuth called on a WebRequest not in STARTED state in onReceivedHttpAuthRequest

Tags: java, android, authentication, webview

I'm trying to get basic authentication working in my app, however I'm getting this error which closes the activity and so I don't get through. Not sure what I'm doing wrong? Maybe calling `handler.proceed` too early?

Error:

```
08-20 09:52:13.793    8627-8836/com.example.app E/external/webkit/Source/WebKit/android/WebCoreSupport/WebRequest.cpp﹕ setAuth called on a WebRequest not in STARTED state (state=5)
```

Code:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler,
                                 String host, String realm) {

    super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);

    if (username == null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        alert.setTitle("Please Log In");
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        // Set an EditText view to get user input
        final EditText usernameInput = new EditText(getActivity());
        usernameInput.setHint("Username");
        usernameInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
        layout.addView(usernameInput);

        final EditText passwordInput = new EditText(getActivity());
        passwordInput.setHint("Password");
        passwordInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        layout.addView(passwordInput);

        alert.setView(layout);

        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                username = usernameInput.getText().toString();
                password = passwordInput.getText().toString();
                reloadWebView();
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                // Canceled.
            }
        });

        alert.show();
    } else {
        handler.proceed(username, password);
    }
```

//Edit:

I've now modified my code so that the username and password are just hardcoded like so:

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler,
                                         String host, String realm) {

    super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);
    handler.proceed("username", "password");
}
```

But same error... No idea what the issue is here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by getting rid of:

```
super.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(view, handler, host, realm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just reading through [the WebRequest.cpp file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/webkit/+/aac3ea764cda8a0b37bd3349510e9001f81e2b65/Source/WebKit/android/WebCoreSupport/WebRequest.cpp) and it looks like the error message your getting is being created in setAuth on line 463 because your WebRequest isnt getting to call the start method on line 231. Try adding a conditional statement before you call proceed to check that username and password arnt null first? Also [take a look at these examples](http://www.codota.com/android/classes/android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler) of similar snippets of code and you may find a solution.

Comment: Hi, you can see from my code that it's all in an if else statement which starts `if (username == null) {`. Neither username or password are null

Comment: opps sorry didnt spot that :)